# How to determine the next delivery day given this table? SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table which lists the delivery days available for an area. Also given are the order date and count of stores with the same order date and delivery day.

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(`order_date` date, `area` varchar(20), `delivery_days` varchar(20), `stores` int)
;

INSERT INTO table1
(`order_date`, `area`, `delivery_days`, `stores`)

VALUES
('2020-11-22', 'A', '1,3,5', 17),
('2020-11-25', 'A', '1,3,5', 4),
('2020-11-26', 'B', '2,4,6', 9),
('2020-11-28','B', '2,4,6', 6);
```

You can read the available delivery days as (1 for Mon, 2 for Tue, 3 for Wed... 6 for Sat).

With that said, if stores from area A ordered on 2020-11-22, Sunday, the nearest delivery day is the next day, 1 Monday. And if stores from the same area ordered on 2020-11-25, Wednesday, the nearest delivery day is 2 days from said date, which is 5 Friday.

```
order_date  area    delivery_days   stores
2020-11-22   A       1,3,5           17
2020-11-25   A       1,3,5           4
2020-11-26   B       2,4,6           9
2020-11-28   B       2,4,6           6
```

What I would like to do is summarize this information into a table that looks like this-- where each column counts the number of stores that fall into the delivery category then gets the percentage relative to the total count of stores.

```
area   total_stores  next_day_delivery   percent   2_day_delivery   percent   3_day_delivery   percent
A       21           17                  81        4                19             
B       15                                         9                60        6                40
```

How can I do this? Here's the sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/784e1/1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: So step 1 is to revise your schema

Comment: Fix your data model!  Don't store numbers in strings!  Don't store multiple values in strings!  Use another table with one row per delivery day and store.